# Can't call defrag from perl script on Windows 2008

Tags: perl, windows-server-2008-r2, defragmentation

I would like to run a perl script that runs the defrag command on windows.  When I try to just use

```
system("defrag C:");
```

I get "'defrag' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file".  I get the same error even if I give the full path of C:\Windows\System32\defrag.exe.  Also, any test for the existence of defrag.exe fails.  For example:

```
if(-f "C:\\Windows\\System32\\defrag.exe"),

if(-x "C:\\Windows\\System32\\defrag.exe"), and

if(-e "C:\\Windows\\System32\\defrag.exe")
```

all fail.  In fact they fail when testing for any .exe file.  This works fine on Windows 2003, does anyone know why it no longer works on Windows 2008?

Thanks!

Chris

**Update**: Backslashes weren't escaped originally. Fixed.

Comment: Hint: In a Perl script, you can use forward slashes for those entires. I.e you can say if ( -f "C:/Windows/System32/defrag.exe"). Try `C:/Windows/SysWow64/defrag.exe`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newer versions of Windows (which may or may not include Windows Server 2008) virtualise certain system directories for executables that weren't built with a manifest instructing otherwise.

Since 5.12.0, Perl is built with this instruction.

> perl.exe now includes a manifest resource to specify the trustInfo settings for Windows Vista and later. Without this setting Windows would treat perl.exe as a legacy application and apply various heuristics like redirecting access to protected file system areas (like the "Program Files" folder) to the users "VirtualStore" instead of generating a proper "permission denied" error.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to escape your backslashes in order for them to be recognized as an actual directory separator:

```
if(-f "C:\\Windows\\System32\\defrag.exe")
```

Should work.

Comment: My bad.  I do actually escape them in my in code, just forgot to do that when typing my post.  As an update, if I manually copy Defrag.exe out of Windows\System32 I can execute it from my script.  I can't copy it programmatically though so it seams like it might be a permissions issue.

Answer (score 0):

I just ran into this issue trying to use `psexec`. You're probably getting hit by the [SystemFile Redirector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384187%28VS.85%29.aspx). It has something to do with reserving the C:\Windows\System32 directory only for 64 bit programs and 32 bit programs can no longer execute 64 bit programs, but are redirected to C:\Windows\SysWow64 directory.

That's Microsoft for you: 64 bit programs are stored in C:\Windows\System32 while 32 bit programs are stored in C:\Windows\SysWow64.

I believe Perl 5.12 is suppose to solve this issue, but I got around it by simply copying the program from the C:\Windows\System32 directory to another directory.

Comment: Perl 5.12 worked. Copying the file gave me this error: "The resource loader cache doesn't have loaded MUI entry".  No idea what that means and googleling gave a lot of references to Norton, but I don't think that's what's causing it.

Comment: Realized I said copying it worked in an above comment.  I should clarify that that was on a co-worker's 2008 box.  My box gave the error when copying the file, so for consistency I'm going to stick with Perl 5.12 as a solution.